# Can't get SharpSSH to connect via FTP

Tags: .net, ftp, sftp, sharpssh

I'm having trouble making a secure FTP connection using SharpSSH. Up to now I've been using the DOS command line app MOVEit Freely to make the connection, and it connects fine:

```
C:\> ftps -user:ABC -password:123 xxx.xxx.xxx.mil
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with SharpSSH, I get an error that says either the connection timed out or the server didn't respond correctly:

```
Dim sftp = New Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp("xxx.xxx.xxx.mil", "ABC", "123")
sftp.Connect()
```

or

```
Dim host = New Tamir.SharpSsh.SshStream("xxx.xxx.xxx.mil", "ABC", "123")
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong, or how I could figure out what's failing?

Note that I need a secure FTP connection, so the .NET classes are not an option. I'm willing to try alternatives to SharpSSH if they exist though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using Tamir.SharpSsh, which is a SSH library. However, it looks like you are connecting to FTPS (or FTP/SSL) server. The FTPS is completely different protocol and has nothing common with SFTP nor SSH.

Following page on our website discusses the differences between FTP, FTP/SSL, FTPS and SFTP protocols: [rebex.net/secure-ftp.net/](http://www.rebex.net/secure-ftp.net/).

Brief summary follows:

- FTP plain, old, insecure file transfer protocol. Transfers clear text password over the network.
- FTPS - FTP over TLS/SSL encrypted
  channel. FTP and FTPS relation is
  similar to HTTP and HTTPS.
- FTP/SSL - same as FTPS
- SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol. Has nothing common with FTP (expect the name). Runs over SSH encrypted communication channel.
- Secure FTP - could be either SFTP or FTPS :-(

You may try [Rebex File Transfer Pack](http://www.rebex.net/file-transfer-pack/) component, which supports both SFTP and FTPS protocols (but it costs some money unlike the SharpSSH).

Connection to FTP/SSL server would look like this:

```
' Create an instance of the Ftp class. 
Dim ftp As New Ftp()

' Connect securely using explicit SSL. 
' Use the third argument to specify additional SSL parameters. 
ftp.Connect(hostname, 21, Nothing, FtpSecurity.Explicit)

' Connection is protected now, we can log in safely. 
ftp.Login(username, password)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another great alternative (also not free) is [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html), a stable, mature library which offers full support for FTPS (and SFTP) in .NET.

Here's some sample code for connecting:

```
   SecureFTPConnection ftpConnection = new SecureFTPConnection();

   // setting server address and credentials
   ftpConnection.ServerAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.mil";
   ftpConnection.UserName = "ABC";
   ftpConnection.Password = "123";

   // select explicit FTPS
   ftpConnection.Protocol = FileTransferProtocol.FTPSExplicit;

   // switch off server validation (only do this when testing)
   ftpConnection.ServerValidation = SecureFTPServerValidationType.None;

   // connect to server
   ftpConnection.Connect();
```